# Symfony4 DateTimeType as single_text widget not formatting correctly

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, datetime-format

This problem is starting to drive me mad and I can't seem to find any correct information or documentation regarding this problem.

I'm using symfony 4.2.3

I have a form with a dateTimeType :

```
 ->add(
            'startDate',
            DateTimeType::class,
            [
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'input' => 'datetime',
                'html5' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'combinedPickerInput',
                    'placeholder' => date('d/m/y H:i'),
                ],
                'format' => 'd/m/Y H:i',
                'date_format' => 'd/m/Y H:i',
                'label' => 'form.specialOffer.startDate',
                'translation_domain' => 'Default',
                'required' => false,
            ]
        )
```

When I submit the form using AJAX the $_POST shows ̀`startDate = '24/04/2019 06:24'`

However as soon as I use the getData() function on my form the value becomes a DateTime object (as it should) but it is not formatted correctly

```
startDate = {
    date = 2018-12-24 06:04:00.000000,
    timezone_type = 3
    timezone = "Europe/Paris"
}
```

The field in my entity is

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $startDate;
```

I have also tried using the DateType instead of the DateTimeType but that doesn't change anything.

```
->add(
            'endDate',
            DateType::class,
            [
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'html5' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'combinedPickerInput',
                    'placeholder' => date('d/m/y H:i'),
                ],
                'format' => 'd/m/Y H:i',
                'label' => 'form.specialOffer.endDate',
                'translation_domain' => 'Default',
                'required' => false,
            ]
        )
```

The result is exactly the same as with the DateTimeType

When looking at the DateTimeType class something seems a bit off.
when setting the date format the code is as follows

```
$dateFormat = \is_int($options['date_format']) ? $options['date_format'] : self::DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT;
```

which to me makes it impossible to use a date_format that is not an int. However the validation and error message just below seem to indicate that it should in fact be possible to pass a string for a custom date format

```
 if (!\in_array($dateFormat, self::$acceptedFormats, true)) {
        throw new InvalidOptionsException('The "date_format" option must be one of the IntlDateFormatter constants (FULL, LONG, MEDIUM, SHORT) or a string representing a custom format.');
    }
```

I am quite lost with this any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try to change the **format option value** with **dd/MM/yyyy H:i** and use DateTimeType instead of DateType

```
->add('endDate', DateType::class, [
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    'html5' => false,
    'attr' => [
        'class' => 'combinedPickerInput',
        'placeholder' => date('d/m/y H:i'),
    ],
    'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy H:i',
    'label' => 'form.specialOffer.endDate',
    'translation_domain' => 'Default',
    'required' => false,
])
```

Comment: Hey thanks that seems to do the trick, it's 'dd/MM/yyyy H:m' the correct format. The fact that the placeholder has a different format threw me off I think.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for the `date_format` option on the `DateTimeType` field. It is not the same as the format used in the `date()` function or `DateTime` classes.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#date-format

The value you set for `date_format` should be an integer; one of the constants listed at https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php#intl.intldateformatter-constants